# How to change the signal button background color in 10 buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am beginner of web development. I wanna build up a game for my friends. When they clikced one of button, the background-color of that button will be changed to red. Now I don't know why all buttons changed backgound-color when I just clicked any signle one button. Please tell me how to amend the code. Thank you so much.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aok6F.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uGMY.png)

Comment: Add your code directly with code block, there is also tool to help you do that! As I see with your code, the problem lies on the line you set the className, it will be true whenever you select a question, className in this case should compare with current question id, something like `currentQuestion.id === q.id`

Answer (score 0):

in classname you can add `q.name === this.state.currentQuestion ? _class[this.state.active] : null (or any default color)` I hope it will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

**Example1**
Styling each button on click

```js
let myBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for(let i = 0; i < myBtns.length; i++){
    myBtns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        myBtns[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn">Button 4</button>
```

**Example 2** 
Toggle the "active" class to style ONLY one button each time

```js
let myBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (var i = 0; i < myBtns.length; i++) {
  myBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn active">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn">Button 4</button>
<button class="btn">Button 5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for understanding, you can do like this as well :

//CSS

```
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

//HTML

```
  <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 3</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 4</button>
```

//JS

```
var numOfButton = $(".btn").length;  // get the number of button elements
    $(".btn").on("click",function(e){   // added click event    
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfButton; i++) { // using loop to remove active class from button, if any.
          $(".btn").removeClass("active");
        }
        $(this).addClass("active"); // adding active class to clicked button.
    })
```